# c++ bool returning true

Tags: c++, boolean, tic-tac-toe

I am making a tic-tac-toe console application and I have it mostly finished. There's a few more things I will add to it, but I am running into a big problem. I have a bool checkwin() function that is supposed to see if the game has been won, but for some reason this function is always returning true whether or not my parameters have been met. This causes the program to end after the first move has been made. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

```
bool checkwin( Boardstatus& BSTAT)
{
    //Row 'A' checkwin
    if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Row 'B' checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B3"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Row 'C' checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C3"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Column 1 checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B1") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C1"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Column 2 checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C2"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Column 3 checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B3") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B3")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C3"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Diagonal upper-left->bottom-right checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C3"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Diagonal lower-left->upper-right checkwin
    else if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("C1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("B2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



int main()
{
//Start of initializing all squares as a blank
Boardstatus BSTAT;
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "A1", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "A2", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "A3", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "B1", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "B2", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "B3", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "C1", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "C2", ' ' );
BSTAT.setsquarestatus( "C3", ' ' );
//End of square initialization

    do
    {
    playerturn(BSTAT);
    } while (checkwin(BSTAT) == false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to be so relieved when you discover arrays.

Comment: Probably haha. I haven't been doing this very long and there's still a lot for me to learn. I'll try using arrays instead of the messy stuff I'm doing now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns true because `' '` is equal to `' '` -- that is, after the first move you are guaranteed that three squares in a row will still be empty and you only test if the square values are *equal* and not that they are *equal and not empty*.

One possible way to fix this:

```
if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")!=' ' &&
    BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2") &&
    BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3"))
```

You would need to add this `... != ' '` check to every conditional, obviously changing the particular square you test.

This may be obvious, but you only have to test one of the squares because if the first square isn't empty and the others are equal to it, then obviously the other squares are not empty either.

Comment: Ah of course. I don't know how I could have missed that. Thank you so much. Also as a side note, why are people downvoting my post? I'm new to this website, did I do something wrong I need to know about?

Comment: @UnclePutin When asking for help with a bug, it's considered polite to reduce your code to a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the bug but without *any* code that is unnecessary to accomplish this. This goes by a few names: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), MVCE, etc. Pasting a wall of code when most of it is unrelated to the problem is frowned upon.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the info. Sorry about that. I'll keep that in mind in the future. I'll go ahead and reduce this one.

Answer (score 0):

you must add an other test, 
for example : 
if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1") != ' ' && 
BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2") != ' ' &&  BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3") != ' ')

do the same for all test

however there is an other better way to implement this algorithm

Comment: What's the better way to do it? I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

by the use of matrices.
int TicTac[3][3] initialized to 0
1 --> Player 1
2 --> Player 2 and check winner will be ` for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if((TicTac[i][0] == 2 && TicTac[i][1]  == 2 && TicTac[i][2] == 2) ||
                (TicTac[i][0] == 1 && TicTac[i][1]  == 1 && TicTac[i][2] == 1)) {

```
            return TicTac[i][0];
        }
        if((TicTac[0][i] == 2 && TicTac[1][i]  == 2 && TicTac[2][i] == 2) ||
            (TicTac[0][i] == 1 && TicTac[1][i]  == 1 && TicTac[2][i] == 1)) {

            return TicTac[0][i];
        }
    }
    if((TicTac[0][0] == 1 && TicTac[1][1] == 1  && TicTac[2][2] == 1 )||
            TicTac[0][0] == 2 && TicTac[1][1] == 2  && TicTac[2][2] == 2) {

        return TicTac[0][0];
    }
    if(TicTac[0][2] == 1 && TicTac[1][1] == 1 && TicTac[2][0] == 1 ||
        TicTac[0][2] == 2 && TicTac[1][1] == 2 && TicTac[2][0] == 2 ) {

        return TicTac[0][2];}
}`
```